# Magento 1.9 Some Attributes in set not showing on product page?

Tags: attributes, magento-1.9

I am having an issue where some attributes in a set are not showing on the product page.  This leads me to think there is a custom list somewhere but for the life of me I can't find it or the code to control this.  This is what I have that is displaying in product template called from attributes.phtml

`<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct() ?><?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="20%" /><col />  <tbody><?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <?php if ($_data['value'] == 'No') continue; ?>
            <tr>                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr><?php endforeach; ?></tbody></table><script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script><?php endif;?>`

Any help with this as I want to show more than what is listed.

Here is the list of attributes in the set.
[image]

Here is options set for ring_size.. its the same as the others that are working.

***EDIT***
I have narrowed it down to custom change in mage core with attributes.php file.

There was some commenting out and custom code entered there causing the issue.

I was hoping someone could help me though write code to;

If an attribute is present show , else show another attribute.
example code being used in this file

```
if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'metal_type' && is_string($value)) {
                $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->metalPrice($value, true);
```

}     else:    echo  '$value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);';

??? something like this.. Sorry im only beginner at php.

Comment: The configuration seems to be correct, change your theme to the default one and check they are coming or not, if they are coming you have to do something with your custom theme.

Comment: please see edits.. I traced it back to mage core file for attributes.php.. although now Im looking for a way to show one attribute if it exists and if not then to show another.